# How do I debug a php nusoap call requiring basic authentication that doesn't respond at all?

Tags: php, nusoap

I am trying to re-write a Drupal module that has fallen behind the API of the gateway it connects to.

A stripped back version of the code I think is causing the problem is as follows:

```
$namespace = ($this->testing) ? 'https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/' : 'https://api.ewaypayments.com/';
$endpoint = $this->url;
$httpUsername = $this->user_name;
$httpPassword = $this->password;

$client = new nusoap_client($endpoint, TRUE);
$client->setCredentials($httpUsername, $httpPassword, 'basic');
$client->response_timeout = 50;
$result = $client->call($operation, array('request' => $params), $namespace);
```

The `$result` is consistently false.  If I put anything like this into my code it also consistently returns `empty`:

```
$error = $client->getError(); 
watchdog('connection_message', $error);
```

I'm a bit out of my depth and without any error messages in my Apache logs or in the Drupal watchdog I cannot see a way forward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Turn on PHP error reporting** if it's not already on.

Check that the `error_reporting`, `display_errors` settings in your `php.ini` file are set to `E_ALL` and `On` respectively when you are developing locally. You can also add these directives at the beginning of your PHP script to set them at run time:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

**2. Catch NuSOAP errors** like this:

```php
$result = $client->call($operation, array('request' => $params), $namespace);
if ($client->fault) {
    echo 'Error: ';
    print_r($result);
} else {
    // check result
    $err_msg = $client->getError();
    if ($err_msg) {
        // Print error msg
        echo 'Error: '.$err_msg;
    } else {
        // Print result
        echo 'Result: ';
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

**3. Verify you are using the correct API parameters and endpoint:**

From the [eWAY API reference](https://eway.io/api-v3/#transparent-redirect), your endpoints are:

> https://api.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx (production)
>   https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx (sandbox)

**4. Similar eWAY API projects** that you can reverse-engineer:

- [Commerce eWAY for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/2062451) (last version is Mar. 2014)
- [eWAY-RapidAPI](https://github.com/fayland/eWAY-RapidAPI-php) (uses JSON and cURL)
- [eWay-PHP-API](https://github.com/samuelwilliams/eWay-PHP-API/) (uses XML and cURL)
- [eWay Payment Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028713/eway-payment-gateway) (uses SOAPClient)

Comment: Yeah it's Commerce eWAY for Drupal that I'm trying to update, it doesn't have support for the Rapid API and tokens don't currently seem to work.

Comment: Your endpoint may be wrong, but you should still receive some error messages. Try checking for that 'fault' flag that I put in my answer as well as enabling PHP errors just in case.

Comment: Your code for catching errors did the trick, thanks very much!  Somehow my authentication isn't working, now I know where to look.  Answer accepted.

Comment: Awesome! I went through the NuSoap source to find the way it reports errors. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would like to say in this case.

First, why do you have to use that library ? You can use `Zend_Soap_Client` (if you don't have it you can install it using [composer](http://getcomposer.org):

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer (look for  `zendframework/zend-soap`)

Then, you can download a trial version of [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/). Its debugging tools when used with http://xdebug.org are really awesome, you can inspect the entire variable and environment space in runtime.

Finally, you can use a friendly error managing tool like http://raygun.io, you insert a few lines of code, create a trial account in there, and in minutes you get all errors that are happening in your application.

In your case, you can see for example the current value of `$operation`, which seems the function being called on the webservice.

Here's the code for inspecting all functions being offered in a webservice using `Zend_Soap_Client`:

```
$endpoint = 'http://your.example.endpoint/?wsdl';
$soapClient = new Zend_Soap_Client($endpoint);
$functions  = $soapClient->getFunctions();
var_dump($functions);
```

Comment: Or just use the native PHP Soap implementation ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, hadn't thought of updating the Soap implementation.  Certainly worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SOAP requests your endpoint is incorrect, it should be https://api.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx or 
https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx

Comment: Ah yes, of course, those values were an attempt to get some kind of error out of the system.  They did end in soap.asmx originally, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Oh, my bad, the endpoint is set much earlier in the code and stored in `$this->url;` the values are as you have described.  Looks like the namespace shouldn't have soap.asmx at the end...

Comment: can you just scrap the namespace it really shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance you may think to disable nusoap debugging.

To check, edit the /include/nusoap/nusoap.php file and set the debug level to 0, like this:

`['nusoap_base']->globalDebugLevel = 0;`

One step even further is to remove all lines that start with:

`$this->debug(`

or

`$this->appendDebug(`

Source:

```
http://kb.omni-ts.com/entry/245/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give this module a try: https://www.drupal.org/project/eway_integration

We are currently working with eWay to test this module together. It works with Drupal Commerce and implements eWay's RAPID 3.1 API and is PCI compliant.